# Have sed -i output to stdout the way just sed does

Tags: linux, sed

When I am running sed operations on a file, for example:

`sed 's/this/that/' /my/file.txt`

The output is displayed on stdout.

However, when I apply the changes in place with `-i` there is no stdout (no output at all to screen).

`sed -i 's/this/that/' /my/file.txt`

How can I still output to screen when I'm using the `-i` trigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. You've probably already noticed that if you

```
sed -i 's/this/that/p' /my/file.txt
```

it just includes that line twice in /my/file.txt.

You can, of course, cheat:

```
sed -i 's/this/that/' /my/file.txt; cat /my/file.txt
```

or, if appropriate

```
sed -i 's/this/that/' /my/file.txt && cat /my.file.txt
```